# UIModalPresentationCurrentContext not showing transparent background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have UIViewController called TestVC who's background is set to clearColor:

```
@implementation TestVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

@end
```

I present the TestVC from another view controller via:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:[[TestVC alloc] init] animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But the present TestVC is white and it obscures the screen. Is there a way to have it transparent or partially obscure the underlying view controller?

Thanks

Comment: What is the color of the window, and try modalPresentationStyle UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet.

Comment: Like the answers suggest, setting the modalPresentationStyle of the TestVC instance instead of doing that to 'self' works.

Answer (score 0):

sorry .. my fault... just like the comment bellow, you have to set the view controller that you're going to present. 
Add this line to the controller where you present the TestVC 
`TestVCClass *TestVC =[[TestVCClass alloc]init]; TestVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext; [self presentViewController:TestVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Erm...both those lines are the same! Did you mean to change the `modalPresentationStyle` in the second instance?!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `modalPresentationStyle` on the TestVC, not the view controller that is doing the presenting.

And if `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` still doesn't work, try `UIModalPresentationCustom`.